# CSS font-face in Internet Explorer shows font different than Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

My problem is when you open http://test.digv.co:81/webfont/test.html on Firefox and Chrome, the font shows up correctly, using the custom `font-face` I set. However, when you use IE, the first Chinese character is not showing correctly.
I have Googled a lot of places and have been able to find no other solution.
If someone could try http://test.digv.co:81/webfont/test.html and check what the problem is, it would be a great help to me.

Comment: Access denied when trying to access the url you mentioned!

Comment: what happens when you take out `src: url('digv.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),`? What else have you tried?

Comment: IE is displaying it in a different font. Its a unicode character, see here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6211/index.htm, and so the font you are specifying it to display in, either cannot be found, or does not contain the character, so the browser is making the decision on its own of which font to use to display it, and the 2 browsers have decided on different fonts

Comment: @LawrenceLiu hi, can you try http://180.166.105.209:81/webfont/test.html, it should be the dns problem.

Comment: @chiliNUT I don't agree with you. The font OP has used is a Simplified Chinese pack and it should not be defaultly installed in OS, thus the browser cannot make "decisions"

Comment: @chiliNUT, hi, thanks for response, what you mentioned is true, but when you visit http://w.digv.cn, in ie and firefox, you would see difference too, besides that, if you use ie developer tool to change ie version to IE7, you will find all titles get appended a chinese character, which is the right form, but it is not in the dom.

Comment: @GeffereyZhang Still access denied, I might be in the black list, give up now.

Comment: @LawrenceLiu, sorry for your trouble, thanks for you help anyway

Answer (score 3):

Happy wedding for someone! I found the problem, it cannot be avoided!

### Firfox and Chrome uses the GBK encoding.

[image]

### IE uses GB2312 encoding, thus the character does not appear correctly.

[image]

### To solve the problem:

Hard, you need to **modify the source font** to match IE as well, **or use a image**, otherwise there will be no solution.

Comment: did you use ie developer tool and change the version to IE7 when visting http://w.digv.cn, you should see a ghost chinese character appended to all titles, which doesnt exist on the dom. but the ghost character is correctly in the font form.

Comment: besides, i use utf-8 on w.digv.cn. so ie and firefox should have the same encoding

Comment: can you try both ttf, woff on IE and Firefox to see if it is a font corruption?

Comment: the best solution is to use a text image like the headlines from Apple http://apple.com